# on pressing tab it is not going into texbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I am creating tab using html css and jquery. I am not using jquery ui. Let me explain the problem.

in tabs there are Many tabs.every tabs contains texbox,drop down,checkbox, etc. for example when user in the first tab. in this tab text boxes are there. when user come to last text box when it is pressing the tabkey it will move to next tab's first element(like textbox/dropdown etc).I created this but it is not moving to tabs textboxes. the code is available on pastebin and js fiddle. i not find find out what is the problem with my code. if you need any clarification plz ask me

It is not going into next tab. lets understand the problem.when i am pressing tab keyit is not going into text box. when user in the last text box of tab1 when it presses the tab key it will move to next tabs textbox. for example in tab 1 there are four text boxes. when user pressing tab key to it will come to text 1 then text box 2 text 3 when in the last text box it press the tab key it will move to next tab2 text box 1. and same thing will follow for next tabs.

Note :please do not suggest tabindex. I want to do using jquery.

Link:[Demo is here][1] bin:-http://pastebin.com/E85NsNtg

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset='utf-8'/>
            <title>jQuery Tabs Demo</title>
            <style>
                * {padding:0; margin:0;}

                html {
                    background:url(/img/tiles/wood.png) 0 0 repeat;
                    padding:15px 15px 0;
                    font-family:sans-serif;
                    font-size:14px;
                }

                p, h3 { 
                    margin-bottom:15px;
                }

                div {
                    padding:10px;
                    width:600px;
                    background:#fff;
                }

                .tabs li {
                    list-style:none;
                    display:inline;
                }

                .tabs a {
                    padding:5px 10px;
                    display:inline-block;
                    background:#666;
                    color:#fff;
                    text-decoration:none;
                }

                .tabs a.active {
                    background:#fff;
                    color:#000;
                }

            </style>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="global.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul class='tabs'>
                <li><a id="ATab1" href='#tab1' >Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a id="ATab2" href='#tab2' >Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a id="ATab3" href='#tab3' >Tab 3</a></li>
                <li><a id="ATab4" href='#tab4' >Tab 4</a></li>
                <li><a id="ATab5" href='#tab5' >Tab 5</a></li>
                <li><a id="ATab6" href='#tab6' >Tab 6</a></li>

            </ul>
            <div id='tab1'>
                <h3>Section 1</h3>
                Fisrt: <input type="textbox" />
                <br />
                Second: <input type="textbox" />
                <br />
                Third: <input type="textbox" />
                <br />
                Fourth: <input type="textbox" />
            </div>
            <div id='tab2'>
                <h3>Section 2</h3>
                Fifth: <input type="textbox" />
                <br />
                Sixth: <input type="textbox" />
            </div>
            <div id='tab3'>
                <h3>Section 3</h3>
                Seventh: <input type="textbox" />
                <br />
                Eighth: <input type="textbox" />
            </div>
            <div id='tab4'>
            <h3>Section 4</h3>
                ninth: <input type="textbox" />
                <br />
                tength: <input type="textbox" />
            </div>
            <div id='tab5'>
            <h3>section 5</h3>
            11: <input type="textbox" />
            <br />
            12: <input type="textbox" />
        </div>

            <div id='tab6'>
            <h3>section 6</h3>
            13: <input type="textbox" />
            <br />
            14: <input type="textbox" />
        </div>



        </body>
    </html>


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/YG94p/3/

(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        if ($('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val() == "") {
            $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val(location.hash)
        }

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val() + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));
        window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().split('#')[0] + $active.attr('href');

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            // Make the old tab inactive.
            $active.removeClass('active');
            //window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().replace($active.attr('href'), '');
            $content.hide();

            // Update the variables with the new link and content
            $active = $(this);
            $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val($active.attr("href"))
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
            window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().split('#')[0] + $active.attr('href');

            // Make the tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();

            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    $(document).on('keydown',function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

        if (keyCode === 9) {
            if(!$('#tab1:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab1') != -1){
                $('#ATab1').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab2').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').show();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').hide();
                $('#tab5').hide(); 


                window.location = "#tab2";
            }
            else if(!$('#tab2:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab2') != -1){
                $('#ATab2').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab3').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').show();

                window.location = "#tab3";
            }
            else if(!$('#tab3:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab3') != -1){
                $('#ATab3').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab4').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').show();
                window.location = "#tab4";
            }

            else if(!$('#tab4:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab4') != -1){
                $('#ATab4').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab5').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').hide();
                $('#tab5').show();
                window.location = "#tab5";
            }

            else if(!$('#tab5:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab5') != -1){
                $('#ATab5').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab6').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').hide();
                $('#tab5').hide();
                 $('#tab6').show(); 
                window.location = "#tab6";
            }

            else if(!$('#tab6:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab6') != -1){
                $('#ATab6').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab1').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').show();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').hide();
                $('#tab5').hide();
                $('#tab6').hide();
                $('#tab7').hide();
                window.location = "#tab1";
            }



        }
            e.preventDefault();

     });
});
```

Comment: The tabs are changing perfectly. What do you want ? here http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/z6g88/

Comment: It is not going into next tab. lets understand the problem.when i am pressing tab keyit is not going into text box. when user in the last text box of tab1 when it presses the tab key it will move to next tabs textbox. for example  in tab 1 there are four text boxes. when user pressing tab key to it will come to text 1 then text box 2 text 3 when in the last text box it press the tab key it will move to next tab2 text box 1. and same thing will follow for next tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You you use `type="textbox"` instead of `type="text"`.

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/z6g88/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        if ($('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val() == "") {
            $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val(location.hash)
        }

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val() + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));
        window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().split('#')[0] + $active.attr('href');

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            // Make the old tab inactive.

            $active.removeClass('active');
            //window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().replace($active.attr('href'), '');
            $content.hide();

            // Update the variables with the new link and content
            $active = $(this);
            $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val($active.attr("href"))
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
            window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().split('#')[0] + $active.attr('href');

            // Make the tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show(this.href);
            var tt = $(this).attr('href')
            $(tt).find('input:eq(0)').focus()
            console.log($(tt).find('input:eq(0)').val())
            //$(this.href).find('.ttt').focus()
            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    $(document).on('keydown',function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

        if (keyCode === 9) {
            if(!$('#tab1:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab1') != -1){
                $('#ATab1').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab2').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').show();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').hide();
                $('#tab5').hide(); 


                window.location = "#tab2";
            }
            else if(!$('#tab2:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab2') != -1){
                $('#ATab2').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab3').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').show();

                window.location = "#tab3";
            }
            else if(!$('#tab3:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab3') != -1){
                $('#ATab3').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab4').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').show();
                window.location = "#tab4";
            }

            else if(!$('#tab4:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab4') != -1){
                $('#ATab4').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab5').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').hide();
                $('#tab5').show();
                window.location = "#tab5";
            }

            else if(!$('#tab5:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab5') != -1){
                $('#ATab5').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab6').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').hide();
                $('#tab5').hide();
                 $('#tab6').show(); 
                window.location = "#tab6";
            }

            else if(!$('#tab6:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('tab6') != -1){
                $('#ATab6').removeClass('active');
                $('#ATab1').addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').show();
                $('#tab2').hide();
                $('#tab3').hide();
                $('#tab4').hide();
                $('#tab5').hide();
                $('#tab6').hide();
                $('#tab7').hide();
                window.location = "#tab1";
            }



        }
            e.preventDefault();

     });
});
```

Comment: cursor is not going into text boxes. one more thing in last text when we press the tab it will move into next text box of tab2. and same thing for other tabs